# MT5/MQL5 How to make 6 trades with different currency

Tags: metaprogramming, algorithmic-trading, mql5, metatrader5

I have manage to open up 6 charts for 6 different currency pairs. Instead of open up position on 6 different pairs, it made 6 trades of the same pair. How do I fix it?

```
string symbol[];
      
   for(int i=0; i > maxNoOfTrades; i--)
   {
      symbol[i]=PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL);
  
      if(symbol[i]==EURUSD)
         return true;
         
      if(symbol[i]==GBPUSD)
         return true;
         
      if(symbol[i]==USDJPY)
         return true;
         
      if(symbol[i]==USDCHF)
         return true;
         
      if(symbol[i]==USDCAD)
         return true;
         
      if(symbol[i]==AUDUSD)
         return true;
   }
   return false;
```

Comment: Do you have more code to show? This does not show how you are opening trades.

Comment: Opening Trades

  Function that parse to trade pairs with no position open

Comment: It is difficult to help without seeing the complete code.

Comment: then can you suggest how to trade multiple symbols with 1 EA?

Comment: You have to use `OrderSend()` in conjunction with `MarketInfo()`. Example: `OrderSend(symbol[i], OP_BUY, 0.1, MarketInfo(symbol[i],MODE_ASK), 50, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, clrNONE);`

Comment: Thanks, let me look into it at how to implement this to my codes.

Comment: problem solved!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a marked Order directly, it is called Position in MQL5.
So you have to open a Position.

Opening a Order will not be marked, only e.g. a Stop / StopLimit Order.

Opening a Position e.g. by following Code:

```js
void OpenBuyPosition(){
   
   for (int attempt = 0; attempt < TRADE_RETRY_COUNT; attempt++){   
      // Vorbereitung / Zuordnung der Variablen
      double lots   = Entry_Amount;
      ulong  ticket = posTicket;
      
      MqlTradeRequest request;
      MqlTradeResult  result;
      ZeroMemory(request);
      ZeroMemory(result);
      
      request.action       = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
      request.symbol       = _Symbol;
      request.volume       = lots;
      request.type         = ORDER_TYPE_BUY;
      request.price        = Ask();
      //request.type_filling = ORDER_FILLING_FOK;
      request.type_filling = orderFillingType;
      request.deviation    = 10;
      //request.sl           = stopLoss;
      request.sl           = 0;
      //request.tp           = takeProfit;
      request.tp           = 0;
      request.magic        = Magic_Number;
      request.position     = ticket;
      request.comment      = IntegerToString(Magic_Number);
      
      bool isOrderCheck = CheckOrder(request);
      bool isOrderSend  = false;
   
      if (isOrderCheck){
         ResetLastError();
         isOrderSend = OrderSend(request, result);
      }
              
      if (isOrderCheck && isOrderSend && result.retcode == TRADE_RETCODE_DONE){
         return;
      }
              
      Sleep(TRADE_RETRY_WAIT);
      Print("Order Send retry no: " + IntegerToString(attempt + 2));              
   }
}
```

You can switch the variable for your needed Symbol with you own code.
Also the Type from Buy to Sell ;-)